# Error with duplicate permissions with different maxSdkVersions (Flutter, reactiveBLE)

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I am using the reactiveBLE library (which is by the way excellent, thank you for that).

However, with the newer version, it brings its own manifest file, so I don´t have to add any permissions to mine. The manifest file of reactiveBLE and one of my app are supposed to be merged together when building the app.

Because different rules are needed for different APIs, reactiveBLE adjusts its permissions accordingly. It seems that for Bluetooth, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION are only needed for APIs 23 - 30.

The code is then (for example):

```
uses-permission-sdk-23
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30"
```

However, as I also include other location services (which do need these permissions for other APIs as well), I would have to remove the "android:maxSdkVersion="30" part. This is also recommended in the official documentation:

[official documentation on how to remove maxSdkVersion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPfqz.png)

However, this is not possible, because the manifest file of reactiveBle is generated automatically each time I build something (and my changes are overwritten again).

The app is working fine, but I am getting errors in the Play Console when uploading the app to the Playstore.

Please advise how I can merge the manifest files properly, so I do not get an error when uploading to the Play Console.

Kind regards
René

Answer (score 2):

This solution from [reactiveBLE issues](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/560) worked for me.

To prevent conflicts with you own permissions, in your AndroidManifest.xml file include:

```
  <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

You will also need to add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" in the manifest tag at the top of the file.